# How do I use MinGW-w64 with Sublime?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw-w64

I am trying to code in C++ and I need a compiler. I got Sublime 3 and MinGW-64 and put MinGW-w64.sublime-build in packages. When I hit ctrl+shift+b the console gives me this error:
 `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Rick\Desktop/test.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['g++', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Rick\\Desktop/test.exe', '-static-libgcc', '-static-libstdc++', '*.cpp', '&', 'C:\\Users\\Rick\\Desktop/test.exe']]
[dir: C:\Users\Rick\Desktop]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]`

This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;    

    int main()      
    {    
        std::cout << "Hello World! " << std::end1;    
        return 0;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the folder containing g++.exe (`.../bin`) to your `PATH`.

You can do so with the following (Windows) command:

```
setx path "%path%;FOLDER_CONTAINING_G++"
```

Comment: i did the exact cmd command and it ran successfully, but the Sublime console gives me the same error. Do I need to replace %path% with something? I also dont know if i have g++. I am very new to coding

Comment: You said you got MinGW-64. I assume you installed it? The installation folder should contain a "bin" folder with all the executables you need. MinGW-64 _contains_ g++ (and gcc, and a lot of other things).

Comment: Ok. Yes, I did install MinGw-64. So run the exact command? Do I have to open the command prompt in a certain folder or something?

Comment: The command is just an easy way to change your `PATH` environment variable. All you have to do is add MinGW64's bin folder (its absolute path) to it. You can find a ton of help on Google.

Comment: so.. this? C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\mingw32\bin

Comment: setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\mingw32\bin"